# QML auto anchoring several items

Tags: qt, qml

I want to lay out several items in a row using anchors programatically. Also I want one item to be stretched, hence I don't set width for this particular item. Looks like QML ignores the fixed width I set for an item.

C++ code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;

    view.setSource(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));

    view.setWidth(640);
    view.setHeight(480);

    view.setTitle("QML auto anchors");

    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Stretching row QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Rectangle {
    id: root
    function update() {
        console.log("----------------------")
        console.log("update called, children count: "+children.length)
        for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {

            console.log("parent: "+children[i].parent)
            console.log(i + " child: " + children[i] + "," + children[i].implicitWidth + "," + children[i].width)

            if(i===0) {
                console.log("first child: "+children[i])
                children[i].anchors.left = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i].parent.left })

            } else if(i===children.length-1) {
                console.log("last child: "+children[i])
                children[i].anchors.right = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i].parent.right } )
            } else {
                console.log("inbetween child: "+children[i] + ", left sibling: " + children[i-1] + ", right sibling: " + children[i+1])
                children[i].anchors.left = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i-1].right })
                children[i].anchors.right = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i+1].left })
            }
        }
    }

    onWidthChanged: update()
    Component.onCompleted: update()
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "red"

    StretchingRow {
        width: parent.width
        height: 30
        color: "purple"

        // width based on content
        Label {
            text: "Label"
        }

        // i want this to be stretched
        SpinBox {
            height: 30
            value: 100
        }

        // fixed width
        Button {
            width: 30
            height: 30
            text: "B1"
        }

        // fixed width
        Button {
            width: 30
            height: 30
            text: "B2"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of the console log:

```
qml: update called, children count: 4
qml: parent: StretchingRow_QMLTYPE_0(0x2ab0be81f50)
qml: 0 child: QQuickLabel(0x2ab0be7f0f0),26,26
qml: first child: QQuickLabel(0x2ab0be7f0f0)
qml: parent: StretchingRow_QMLTYPE_0(0x2ab0be81f50)
qml: 1 child: QQuickSpinBox(0x2ab0bfdd230),140,-26
qml: inbetween child: QQuickSpinBox(0x2ab0bfdd230), left sibling: QQuickLabel(0x2ab0be7f0f0), right sibling: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfe8950)
qml: parent: StretchingRow_QMLTYPE_0(0x2ab0be81f50)
qml: 2 child: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfe8950),100,610
qml: inbetween child: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfe8950), left sibling: QQuickSpinBox(0x2ab0bfdd230), right sibling: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfea700)
qml: parent: StretchingRow_QMLTYPE_0(0x2ab0be81f50)
qml: 3 child: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfea700),100,30
qml: last child: QQuickButton(0x2ab0bfea700)
```

My question is, how to achieve my goal without typing every single items and anchors?

Comment: Have you considered using `QtQuick.Controls.Layout`? I think you would be able to very much do what you want with no effort

Comment: Just wanted to have something simple container where I throw in the items and the container will take care of the (re)sizing. Layout requires a lot of extra steps for each item like min/max/preferred width. Also I'm missing stretch factors like in Qt widgets.

Comment: Anchors don't see whether `width` was hard-coded or not. You have to provide the information about the stretching item to your `StretchingRow` (example by a `stretchingColumn` property) and anchor everything with the same or lower index to the left sibling (or parent at index 0) and anchor everything with the same or higher index to the right sibling (or parent for the last item).

Comment: I also expect that no bindings neither the `update()` on `width`changes are necessary as the `item.left` is not a `x` position but instead an anchoring target. Instead you might want to do `update()` when the `children` property has changed.

Comment: @JohannesMatokic, you are correct! Thank you!